# Add expression with BinaryExpression as parameter

Tags: c#, expression-trees

How can I perform nested addition operations using `Expression`? `Expression.Lambda<>` expected parameters to be of type `ParameterExpression`, but one of my parameters is a result of addition so its type is `BinaryExpression`. They don't derive from each other so I cannot cast them and I cannot find any way to convert from `BinaryExpression` to `ParameterExpression`.

Example:

```
var left = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var rightLeft = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var rightRight = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var right = Expression.Multiply(rightLeft, rightRight);

var add = Expression.Add(left, right);

var multiplyResult = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, int>>(right, rightLeft, rightRight).Compile()(5, 3);
var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, int>>(add, left, Expression.Parameter(typeof(int))).Compile();
```

Last line throws

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'variable '' of type 'System.Int32'
>   referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'

Expression should compile to:

```
var result = left + (rightLeft * rightRight);
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] question and show how expression should look if you write it by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Compile` just once and refer result of multiplication in other binary expression. Try this code:

```
var inputType = typeof(int);

var left = Expression.Parameter(inputType, "left");
var rightLeft = Expression.Parameter(inputType, "rightLeft");
var rightRight = Expression.Parameter(inputType, "rightRight");

var multiply = Expression.Multiply(rightLeft, rightRight);
var add = Expression.Add(left, multiply);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, int, int>>(add, left, rightLeft, rightRight);
Console.WriteLine(lambda.ToString()); // will print "(left, rightLeft, rightRight) => (left + (rightLeft * rightRight))"

var result = lambda.Compile().Invoke(1, 2, 3);

Console.WriteLine(result); // will print "7"
```

Comment: What happens if I don't know at compile time how many arguments I have? I am actually building quite a big expression, my example maybe was too simple. Is there a way to specify `Lambda<Func<int, int, int, int>>` dynamically at run time?

Comment: @FCin you can inspect incoming expression with ExpressionVisitor and find out how many arguments you need to pass. However it would be better if you edit your question again and add more specific example of what you want to generate